# How to use ldapdelete to remove a group member?

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap

If I run `ldapsearch -x -ZZ -b 'cn=sysadmin,ou=groups,dc=sub,dc=mydom,dc=com'` I get a list of users in the `sysadmin` group (below). I'd like to remove `user456` only from the `sysadmin` group but I want to do this from a shell script and not create an intermediate LDIF file to do it. What `dn` woudl I use to do this?

eg: `ldapdelete -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// <some_dn_with_the_member_attribute>`

```
# sysadmin, groups, sub.mydom.com
dn: cn=sysadmin,ou=groups,dc=sub,dc=mydom,dc=com
cn: sysadmin
objectClass: top
objectClass: groupOfNames
member: uid=user123,ou=people,dc=sub,dc=mydom,dc=com
member: uid=user456,ou=people,dc=sub,dc=mydom,dc=com
member: uid=user789,ou=people,dc=sub,dc=mydom,dc=com
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this will do it although I can't believe the level of janky needed to get it done:

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:///  << EOF
dn: cn=sysadmin,ou=groups,dc=sub,dc=mydom,dc=com
delete: member
member: uid=user456,ou=people,dc=sub,dc=mydom,dc=com

EOF
```

Comment: Well, the `changeType: modify` is unnecessary as it's implied by `ldapmodify`, but yes, some systems do have irreducible complexity. You could always wrap this in a function/shell script, heredocs can have variables in them.

Comment: Works for me I guess. I've edited out  `changeType: modify` as you suggested. Thanks for looking it over.